# Remove empty {} in JSON

Tags: json

I have JSON which is something like this

```
Var myObj = {{},{'test': '1'}}
```

I would like to remove the `{}` so end up like

```
{'test':'1'}.
```

How can do this?

Comment: How about a regular expression?

Comment: Could you be a little more precise about what it looks like? Is the outer level really an object? If so, I don't see any member names...

Answer (score 0):

This is totally not valid JSON. You'll get an error if you actually try to assign that not-JSON to a variable ("Var" should be lowercase by the way).

You'll need to convert it to a string (actually presumably it is a string already because it's invalid as an object), use a regex to replace the offending invalid JSON, and then convert back to JSON.

```
var myObjStr = "{{},{'test': '1'}}";
var validMyObjStr = myObjStr.replace(appropriateRegEx, '');
var myObj = eval('(' + validMyObjStr + ')');
```

If you need it, I can build an appropriate RegEx for you. Just drop a comment. But really, you should probably fix whatever's giving you the invalid JSON in the first place.